# Passing Queue to Threadpool - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, pool

Getting confused using pool with list vs queues.  I get the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when passing q.get in place of a list.  Hopefully it's just an oversight.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool 
import Queue

numbers = [11,12,13,14]

def printNumbers(n):
    print n

q = Queue.Queue()    
for i in (1,2,3,4):
   q.put(i)

#multiThread with list numbers
pool = Pool(4) 
results = pool.map(printNumbers, numbers)
pool.close() 
pool.join() 

#multiThread with queue
pool2 = Pool(4) 
results2 = pool2.map(printNumbers, q.get())
pool2.close() 
pool2.join()
```

Comment: why do you want to use a queue at this point. And btw. be aware between the differences of threading and multiprocesing

Comment: Queue as it will be growing as the threads are pulling from it (researching thread vs multiprocessing now). 

End goal is a script that walks a directory, and creates a fileInfo var used in a pycurl command, then outputs to a log.  

Right now in order -> parse walk, grab next file, pull info from root path, upload via curl, output to log pass/fail.  Hitting huge time delays on the curl so using threads 

Future goal -> Parse walk, fill queue with file info -> pull from queue with multiple threads doing curl command -> fill logQueue with success/fail -> function pull from logQueue to write out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Queue class does not implement the iterable protocol. You'll need to provide your own Queue implementation that does.  Here is an example:

```
class IterableQueue(Queue.Queue):

    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, maxsize)
        self.put(self._sentinel)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.get, self._sentinel)
```

You can read the details of `__iter__` and how the sentinel is used at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter

Please note that my example queue is not what you want if you want a queue that will block when empty until more items are added.  For that, see [Python iterable Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288158/python-iterable-queue)

However, when I used that version with your code, it never terminated. To use that one, you'll need to restructure a bit so that you can call the close method when you know you have no more items to add to the queue.